# Where is my Creditor Badge?

Tags: support, documentation, badges

I have answered a question with a citation to the Documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820274/what-kind-of-logical-operation-is-this-called-ex-var-var-string1-str/41820329#41820329). Hence I expected I will be awarded the **[Creditor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5851/creditor)** badge, but it wasn't awarded.

Any idea of what happened there ?

**Edit:**

As @Sayse mentioned in comments, *Creditor* is only awarded 364 times, since July '16. Is this normal ?

And as @MartijnPieters mentioned, there may be more requirements to to be awarded the badge. What are those ?

Comment: In the future, please do not answer obvious duplicates.

Comment: Well I posted this question asking about a badge, all I got was some down-votes on my mentioned answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a bug here or if documentation just isn't working, the creditor badge has only been awarded 364 times since July '16?..

Comment: @Sayse Yeah. I also noticed that. May be a bug ?

Comment: I'm not sure, its just as likely that documentation just isn't working (yet?)

Comment: @Sayse Yeah. Probably.

Comment: Yes, I downvoted all of those answers. But I left you a comment explaining why, so you should be happy. If I've learned anything on Meta, it's that all anyone wants for Christmas is a comment to accompany downvotes. Now, I'm sure the fact that you answered an obvious duplicate has nothing to do with why you're not being awarded a Creditor badge, and as for the question, *"Does Documentation need more work?"*, the answer is *clearly and resoundingly yes*.

Comment: @CodyGray So you are saying that answering a possible duplicate, is a _wrong doing_ here ? That's new to me. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, answering an obvious duplicate is wrong. I don't know how that could possibly be new to you. What would be the point in answering something that has already been answered thoroughly somewhere else?

Comment: @CodyGray I get what you are saying. Yes. That may not beneficial for most of the people. But I only tried to help the guy. But yeah. I get it now. I will avoid answering those kind of question hereafter. Thanks.

Comment: Another possibility exists: that there are more implicit requirements that you haven't met yet; I just don't know what those would be. The badge is actively being awarded still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought the requirements which have been mentioned there are exhaustive. Is there anyone who knows what exactly the requirements is ?
It's better to mention them there right ?

Comment: Loads of badges have implicit requirements to block cheating. The creditor badge requires an upvote, for example. See [Creditor badge not received](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334454) and [Creditor badge possible bug?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329086). The linked example also needs to have been upvoted: [Creditor badge not received on upvoted answer](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341449). There may be other such criteria.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks. So there are more requirements right. (But the example I've linked is also up-voted, as well as my answer). Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: I found a related bug last night - apparently we don't track things correctly for first revisions of answers. I'm working on fixing it today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I found a few issues with the badge. Namely, the SQL query for it had some bugs, and we didn't correctly track links added in the very first revisions of answers. All those issues have been corrected now.

For future reference, here are the full criteria for the badge:

- the link is posted in an answer that isn't deleted
- the link is added by the answer's author
- the answer receives an upvote after the link was added
- the link still exists in the current revision of the answer
- the answer's author has never contributed to the topic or example being referenced